# How might I output formatted text to the screen without having to write each time the relevant escape sequences?

Tags: formatting, macros, racket, stdout, string-interpolation

I am aware that I can display formatted text in Racket with `display` like so:
`(display "\33[3mSth in italic\33[m without any macro.\n")`
Much like I would do it in Bash:

```
ita='\e[3m'
end='\e[0m'

echo -e "${ita}This is in italics${end}."
```

or in Python:

```
italic = '\33[3m'
end = '\33[m'

print(f"{italic}This is in italic{end}")
```

Every time I create a new `.sh` or `.py` file the file gets prepended with the relevant [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and the above boilerplate. This way I don't have to travel my poor memory the escape sequences as the process get automated away? How might I accomplish the same in Racket?
I've tried with macros and `format`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env racket
#lang racket

(define-syntax ita
    (lambda (stx)
      (syntax "\33[3m")))
(define-syntax fi
    (lambda (stx)
      (syntax "\33[m")))
      
(format "In ~aitalic~a without macro." "\33[3m" "\33[m")
(format "In ~aitalic~a with macro." ita fi)
```

but I am unable to obtain the desired result.
I would like to solve this within Racket. Let other solutions,
e.g. modifying the file with `sed`, be outside of the scope of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Racket has a few libraries for colorizing text with ANSI escape sequences. [colorize](https://docs.racket-lang.org/colorize/index.html) is a decently full featured one:

```lisp
#lang racket
(require colorize)

(display "Plain")
(display (colorize "Italic" 'default #:style 'italic))
(display "Plain")
(newline)
```

Comment: Note that the package has to be installed with the DrRacket package manger or from the command line with `raco pkg install colorize`